# Can you use part of the email subject to populate the To field in the Email Outbound Point in mule?

Tags: email, mule, substring

I have an Email to Email flow that needs to send specific senders depending on the email subject. I was using #[message.inboundProperties.subject.substring(40,3) to get the value but its ending up in error. I'm not sure which function to use to get the value I need from the subject since the order number is also there. Any tips? All my needed values are on the subject line at the moment.

Also, Can I use this value to generate an email body for the message?

To: [Sender]

Hi [Sender]

Your order no [Order] was successfully imported

Thanks Mule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question that comes to mind is from where are you getting the Subject ? Is it a Fixed statement ?

What you can do is other way round. You can store the `[Order]` and `[Sender]` in flow variables and then you can construct a Subject line and email body out of it.

For example let you store your `[Order]` in a flow variable as follows:-

```
<set-variable variableName="Order" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'order']" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

and `[Sender]`  in another flow variable :-

```
<set-variable variableName="Sender" value="someone@example.com" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Then you can send `[Order]` and `[Sender]` in subject line :-

```
Hi #[flowVars.Sender.split('@')[0]] your order number #[flowVars.Order] is ready
```

And in email body you can write as following :-

```
Hi #[flowVars.Sender.split('@')[0]]

Your order no#[flowVars.Order] was successfully imported

Thanks Mule
```

Please note I have used `flowVars.Sender.split('@')[0]` to get the sender name from email address ...
reference :- [How can I extract the user name from an email address using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266608/how-can-i-extract-the-user-name-from-an-email-address-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi Anirban,Thanks for the helpful suggestion. I was doing the same logic now. Btw,  how are you writing the email body as I can only see the header fields on the SMTP outbound point. Also, your are right Im trying to get the value from the the subject substring. May only issue would be when this changes. Im looking on how to get the value from the end of the subject line for my substring count. Do you have any idea for that? Thanks again as Im still learning mule and string manipulations

Comment: You can set payload to set the email body ... Mule payload serves as email body.. If you want to have formatted email body, you can refer here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178799/sending-formatted-mails-with-mule   and BTW, it is very bad Idea to extract value from a long subject line and that too it's not fixed length... you could have the sender value with you and can put that in subject line at the end doing it other way

Comment: Thanks again, I will take note all of your suggestions. I have no other way to get the sender and order number since its coming from an external system that places it on the subject line. Do you have any idea on how to read this from the last character since the last string will be the time stamp and the before that is the value that I need. Thanks Again

Comment: Warehouse XML Import Succeeded - Knauff_ROC_3510254_0403201610290345.xml is my filename and I need to get the 'ROC and the number after that for the Order.

Comment: Pls write the entire subject line here and the word you need to extract from it

Comment: Hi Anirban, I would like to extract ROC and the order number from Above line. I used a choice flow to differentiate the success and failures to get the fixed lengths but I reckon it will be better to get it from the substring of the last character.

Comment: Also, I can see that the previous attachments are being included in the new mail. Is there a way to remove this as well?

Comment: You need to use `<remove-attachment/>`  to remove attachment previous attachment. Here are few link to extract word from the subject using java code... for reference :- http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90474/extracting-a-sentence-containing-a-specific-word-from-a-longer-text   you can use java component or expression component to do so

Comment: Thanks Mate! you have been very helpful. I manage to make it working. Its not that pretty yet and still needs some fine tuning but its a great start. good stuff. Thanks again